# Footer doesn't stay on bottom

Tags: html, css

When the width of the page gets smaller, the footer jumps "in the middle" of the page.

I tried  setting position ablsolute and bottom 0 but then , it stayed in the middle all the time.

Also set html height to 100% and nothing happened. Anybody knows what's the problem?

Thanks in advance.

https://codepen.io/hmarinos/pen/QWayGWJ

```css
* {
  border-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

img:hover {
  border-color: rgb(0, 250, 0);
}

#header-img {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
}

#img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.nav-link a:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 250, 0);
}

#nav-bar {
  align-self: center;
}

.form_container {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: black;
}

#form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 40px;
}

input {
  padding: 8px 0;
  border: none;
}

#email {
  width: 400px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

#submit {
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eee;
  border-width: 1px;
}

#submit:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 75%;
  height: 1800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.column {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px grey;
}

.column h5 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.column h5 p {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.pricing {
  height: 52%;
  margin-top: -22px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.pricing_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

#link_one {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: transparent;
}

#link_one:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#link_two {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#link_two:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

#below_button {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.plans {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.checks {
  width: 100%;
}

.checks ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.checks ul li:before {
  content: '✓';
  padding-right: 8px;
  color: rgb(0, 230, 0);
}

ul li {
  text-indent: -1.25em;
}

.separator {
  height: 1px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1180px) {
  .plans {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .column {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

.video_container {
  width: 75%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.benefits {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 300px;
}

.items {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.items i {
  margin: 26px 0;
}

.icons_text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.icons_text p {
  padding: 26px 0;
}

.fa-solid {
  color: rgb(0, 250, 0);
}

.footer {
  width: 75%;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  position: static;
}

.contact_info {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icons_left ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px 30px;
}

.icons_left ul li {
  padding: 0 40px;
  color: white;
}

.contact_right {
  font-size: 1.05em;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: white;
}

.footer .fa-2x:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 250, 0);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="header-img">
        <img id="img" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/gorilla/gorilla_PNG18705.png" alt="">
        <h1>Gorilla Drive</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="nav-bar">
        <nav id="links">
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Benefits</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:98px;"></div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="plans">
        <div class="column">
          <h5>Basic<br>
            <p>100 GB</p>
          </h5>
          <div class="pricing">
            <div class="pricing_content">
              <a id="link_one" href="#">$2,99/month</a>
              <i id="below_button">Pay annualy (save 100%)</i>
              <a id="link_two" href="">$20,99/year</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="separator"></div>
          <div class="checks">
            <ul class="check_links">
              <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor lahim.</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h5>Standard<br>
            <p>1 TB</p>
          </h5>
          <div class="pricing">
            <div class="pricing_content">
              <a id="link_one" href="#">$2,99/month</a>
              <i id="below_button">Pay annualy (save 100%)</i>
              <a id="link_two" href="">$20,99/year</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="separator"></div>
          <div class="checks">
            <ul class="check_links">
              <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor lahim.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor lahim baban.</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h5>Premium<br>
            <p>2 TB</p>
          </h5>
          <div class="pricing">
            <div class="pricing_content">
              <a id="link_one" href="#">$2,99/month</a>
              <i id="below_button">Pay annualy (save 100%)</i>
              <a id="link_two" href="">$20,99/year</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="separator"></div>
          <div class="checks">
            <ul class="check_links">
              <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor lahim.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor lahim baban.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor lahim baban sahim.</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="benefits">
        <div class="items">
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-fire fa-3x"></i>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-jet-fighter-up fa-3x"></i>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-user-group fa-3x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="icons_text">
            <p><b>High quality!</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper posuere nisi eu finibus.</p>
            <p><b>Jet Fast support!</b> Proin feugiat sem tellus, commodo lacinia dui viverra ac. Sed sollicitudin non metus sed sagittis. Nunc at tincidunt magna.</p>
            <p><b>Share with your family!</b> Aliquam vel mi blandit, venenatis risus vel, pellentesque nisl. Suspendisse et sem leo.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="video_container">
        <h4>What a video!</h4>
        <iframe id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="form_container">
      <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submi">
        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="email">
        <input id="submit" type="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="contact_info">
      <div class="icons_left">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa-brands fa-github fa-2x"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa-brands fa-steam fa-2x"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa-brands fa-cc-visa"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa-brands fa-cc-mastercard"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa-brands fa-cc-apple-pay"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa-brands fa-google-pay"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa-brands fa-cc-paypal"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa-brands fa-cc-amex"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      <div class="contact_right">
        <i><b>Our email:</b> <br>example@123.com</i>
        <p><b>Our address:</b> <br>Catherine st. 29 New York</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Fixed height is the problem in `.main` class. Don't use fix height in `.video_container` and `.main` classes

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked.. btw I used fixed position on video because with width:__% and height auto, the video player would be very short..like 200 px...Should I just skip the main height in general? (I used 100% and it worked}.

Comment: @richard, answers go down there. You short-circuit the SO routine when you post them as comments. Please take the [tour].

Comment: @Play I use this for YT videos : https://www.benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have an errant closing  tag at the end before the closing body tag. I deleted it, and it looks like it addressed the issue.